# Logstash output plugin for JDBC/mySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, logstash

I am collecting Twitter and Instagram data using Logstash and I want to save it to Elasticsearch, MongoDB, and MySQL. There are Logstash output plugins available for Elasticsearch and MongoDB but not for MySQL (it is a requirement to save this data to multiple databases). 
Any workaround for this?
Thanks!

Comment: This plugin should help: https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc

Comment: Should be noted that this plugin is no longer maintained as per authors blog : https://theangryangel.co.uk/blog/archiving-logstash-output-jdbc/

Answer (score 4):

You should install plugin ouput-jdbc for logstash. Download from https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc/tree/master And build、install 。

And then you can use like this:

```
input {
  stdin{}
}

filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
  stdout{
        codec=>rubydebug{}
  }
  jdbc {
    connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://192.168.119.202:3306/outMysql?user=root&password=root"
        statement => ["INSERT INTO user(userName,ip) values(?,?)","userName","ip"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be noted that this plugin is no longer maintained as per authors blog : https://theangryangel.co.uk/blog/archiving-logstash-output-jdbc/

Comment: Then what should be used? This can have vulnerabiltiies. Why elasticsearch does not provide support for the same.